# Is this animal really missing?

Tags: pattern

Considering the sequence :

> Queen, Sport, People and Show, Band, Python, Game, Nuclear, Sea....

What comes next ? Cat or dog ? Is it really missing ?

Comment: Is the 'and' between People and Show intentional, or should it be another comma?

Comment: The and is intentional

Comment: edit : corrected mistake in oredring.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This pattern seems to revolve about the

> planets of our solar system.

Connections with the sequence:

> Queen - Freddie Mercury
>  Sport - Venus Williams
>  People and Show - people live on Earth and the rated TV show Planet Earth
>  Band - the rock band Mars
>  Python - Project Jupyter which supports the Julia, Python and R languages
>  Game - Sega Saturn
>  Nuclear - Uranium was named in 1789 after the recently discovered planet Uranus
>  Sea - Neptune is the Roman god of the sea

What comes next ? Cat or dog ? Is it really missing ? This space may be filled by

> Pluto the cartoon dog, but it's been demoted as a planet so isn't missing.

Comment: OK for everything !, except for "Show", where I was actually thinking of a more saucy connection : (r13) ersreraprf "gur Zbba", nf "zbbavat fbzrbar" vf fubjvat fbzrbar ... fghss.

Comment: Also, band was (r13) guvegl frpbaqf gb Znef, but that's to taste

Comment: @Soltius You might consider using this format for [rot13 comments](//puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6577), since you use them a lot:  rot13(Uv zbz!). One of our regulars [wrote a userscript](//stackapps.com/q/7927) to decode rot13 text on hover, and using that format for such text is a welcome convenience for those of us with that userscript.

Comment: And here I was thinking going to rot13.com every time to decode was half the fun... Thanks for the tip, will start using it !

Comment: (r13) Gurer jnf nyfb n onaq va gur 80f pnyyrq Zneef

Comment: rot13(Cyhgb vf nyfb n png va n Cbr fgbel gvgyrq "Gur Oynpx Png.")